# Suppose that $G$ is a left group acts on $X$ and let be $g \in G$, and $x \in X$. Show that $gG_{x}g^{-1} = G_{gx}$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

**RIGHT ANSWER:**

First inclusion: if $a \in G_x$ then $gag^{-1} \cdot gx= gax=gx$ thus $gag^{-1} \in G_{gx}$.

Second inclusion: if $b\in G_{gx}$ then defining $a=g^{-1}bg$ we have $ax=g^{-1}bgx=g^{-1}gx=x$ therefore $a \in G_x$ so $b=gag^{-1} \in gG_{x}g^{-1}$.

**MY ANSWER:**

By hypotesis we have: left action of group $G$ on $X$, which means there is a function $f:G \times X \rightarrow X$ given by $(g, x) \longmapsto f(g, x):=gx$.

Now, let's consider these groups:

$G_x=\{h \in G: hx=x\}$

$G_{gx}=\{h \in G: hgx=gx\}$

$\color{red}{gG_xg^{-1}=\{ghg^{-1} \in G: ghg^{-1}x=x\}}$ **(Did I write properly this group?)**

For me, in my imagination what I need to proof is $G_{gx}=gG_xg^{-1}$ this is, $\{h \in G: hgx=gx\}=\{ghg^{-1} \in G: ghg^{-1}x=x\}$. So I started as follows:

**$(\supseteq)$** Let be $h \in G_{gx}\implies hgx=gx\implies g^{-1}hgx=g^{-1}gx=x\implies g^{-1}hgx=x.$ Here we found that $g^{-1}hg=x \in G_x$. Then because $x=g^{-1}hgx$ thus (multipling by $g$ in the left side and by $g^{-1}$ in the right side) we have $gxg^{-1}=gg^{-1}hgxg^{-1}\implies gxg^{-1}=hgxg^{-1} \in gG_xg^{-1}$. **(is my answer also right?)**

$(\subseteq)$ Let be $ghg^{-1}\in gG_xg^{-1}$ then $ghg^{-1}x=x$. Now I don't know how to achieve that this element belongs to $G_{gx}$. **Look, that I'm trying to take an element inside $gG_xg^{-1}$ and not inside $G_x$ as in the right answer given. Is it possible?**

Comment: Your interpretation of $gG_x g^{-1}$ is not correct. It should be $\{ghg^{-1} : hx=x\}$.

Comment: I didn't understand why It should be $\{ghg^{−1}:hx=x\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h\in G_x\implies ghg^{-1}(gx)=gh(x)=gx\implies ghg^{-1}\in G_{gx}$.

You got hung up because you assumed $ghg^{-1}x=x$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, this answer is exactly the same as in the **right answer** above. I didn't understand why I need take an element inside $G_x$. Because what I need to show is that $gG_xg^{-1} \subset G_{gx}$. Is not $gG_xg^{-1}$ a set, where I can take elements?

Comment: Yes it is.  But the way to do that is to take an element $h\in G_x$, and then look at $ghg^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.